# Android: developing for froyo and up, want to disable tablet support

Tags: android

There were other posts on this, but I'm still not understanding what I need to do to not allow tablets to download my app. I'll need more time to optimize for tablets, but for now I want to leave it out.

I found this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html
But, again I'm confused since there is a warning that disabling xlarge will sometimes turn on compatibility mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`<compatible-screens>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) element to indicate what combinations of screen size and density you support. You will not appear in the Android Market for any other combination.

Here is the example from the documentation, showing a `<compatible-screens>` element set up for `-small` and `-normal` screen support, but not `-large` and `-xlarge`:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: my minimum sdk is 8, and this method started in 9. I never really got how everything works, but will this code just be ignored in 8, or will it crash?

Comment: @Adam: It is not used at all by Android itself. Quoting the documentation I linked to above: "The Android system does not read the <compatible-screens> manifest element (neither at install-time nor at runtime). This element is informational only and may be used by external services (such as Android Market) to better understand the application's compatibility with specific screen configurations and enable filtering for users."

Comment: if I'm using api 8 the manifest gives an error if I add the above code.

Comment: @Adam: You need to set your build target to API Level 9 or higher. Your app can still have a lower `android:minSdkVersion`.

Comment: @CommonsWare You're right on. This was helpful for me, too.  Thanks much!  I've added this to the arsenal.

Comment: Is it the project build target? or is there something I set in the manifest?

Comment: @Adam you can change your build target to 9 by editing your properties and simply include the following declaration in your manifest: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

Comment: @Adam: You need to set your *project* build target to API Level 9 or higher.